# Why won't AVFoundation accept my planar pixel buffers on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, yuv, avassetwriter, cvpixelbuffer

I've been struggling to figure out what the problem is with my code. I'm creating a planar `CVPixelBufferRef` to write to an `AVAssetWriter`. This pixel buffer is created manually through some other process (i.e., I'm not getting these samples from the camera or anything like that). On the iOS Simulator, it has no problem appending the samples and creating a valid output movie.

But on the device, it immediately fails at the first sample and provides less than useless error information:

`AVAssetWriterError: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12fd2c670 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}`

I'm very new to pixel formats, and I wouldn't be surprised if I've somehow created invalid pixel buffers, but the fact that it works just fine on the Simulator (i.e., OS X) leaves me confused.

Here's my code:

```
const int pixelBufferWidth = img->get_width();
const int pixelBufferHeight = img->get_height();

size_t planeWidths[3];
size_t planeHeights[3];
size_t planeBytesPerRow[3];
void* planeBaseAddresses[3];

for (int c=0;c<3;c++) {
  int stride;
  const uint8_t* p = de265_get_image_plane(img, c, &stride);

  int width = de265_get_image_width(img,c);
  int height = de265_get_image_height(img, c);

  planeWidths[c] = width;
  planeHeights[c] = height;
  planeBytesPerRow[c] = stride;

  planeBaseAddresses[c] = const_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
}

void* descriptor = calloc(1, sizeof(CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrPlanar));
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBufferRef;
CVReturn result = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(NULL,
                                                     pixelBufferWidth,
                                                     pixelBufferHeight,
                                                     kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar,
                                                     NULL,
                                                     0,
                                                     3,
                                                     planeBaseAddresses,
                                                     planeWidths,
                                                     planeHeights,
                                                     planeBytesPerRow,
                                                     &pixelBufferReleaseCallback,
                                                     NULL,
                                                     NULL,
                                                     &pixelBufferRef);


CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(NULL, pixelBufferRef, &formatDescription);

if (assetWriter == nil) {
  // ... create output file path in Caches directory

  assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:fileOutputURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:nil];

  NSDictionary *videoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264,
                                  AVVideoWidthKey : @(pixelBufferWidth),
                                  AVVideoHeightKey : @(pixelBufferHeight),
                                  AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : @{AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : @1}};

  assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings sourceFormatHint:formatDescription];
  [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];

  NSDictionary *pixelBufferAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar),
                                          (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey : @(pixelBufferWidth),
                                          (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(pixelBufferHeight)};

  pixelBufferAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:pixelBufferAttributes];

  [assetWriter startWriting];
  [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
}

samplePresentationTime = CMTimeMake(frameIndex++, framesPerSecond);

BOOL success = [pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBufferRef withPresentationTime:samplePresentationTime];
```

`success` is always `NO`, and the error from the asset writer is what I pasted above.

I also tried creating the sample buffers manually instead of using `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` just to eliminate that as a possible problem, but the results are the same.

Again, this **does** work on the Simulator, so I know my pixel buffers do contain the right data.

Also, I verified that I can write to the file destination. I tried creating a dummy file at that location, and it succeeded.

I would like to avoid converting my buffer to RGB since I shouldn't have to. I have Y'CbCr buffers to begin with, and I want to just encode them into an H.264 video, which supports Y'CbCr.

The source that is creating these buffers states the following:

`The image is currently always 3-channel YCbCr, with 4:2:0 chroma.`

I confirmed that it always enters its loop logic that deals with 8-bit YUV channels.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most likely problem is that some of your parameters are wrong. Create a movie that encodes data as YUV and then check the returned values for each parameter you want to pass into CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(). Make sure that width x height and the num bytes match exactly, there may be padding involved and you have to make sure that everything matches exactly.

Comment: @LucasTizma, have you get any solution for this issue? I am facing same problem while write 420YUV pixelformat samplebuffer data write to File for h264 encoding.

Comment: @Punita See my answer below. You need to use a bi-planar pixel buffer format for iOS as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

So, I can't confirm this officially, but it appears that `AVAssetWriter` doesn't like 3-plane pixel formats (i.e., `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar`) on iOS. On OS X, it appears to work with pretty much anything. When I converted my 3-plane buffers to a bi-planar pixel buffer format, this worked on iOS. This is unsurprising since the camera natively captures in `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` pixel format, so AV Foundation would likely also work with that format.

Still, it'd be nice if I didn't have to do this explicit conversion step myself, though `vImageConvert_PlanarToChunky8` helps to interleave the Cb and Cr planes into a single plane.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm standing in front of the same issue. The `AVAssetWriter` fails to append planar images, but (manually created) bi-planar images work fine.

Would you mind to share, how you used the `vImageConvert_PlanarToChunky8` ?

Comment: I don't recall exactly what I did, and I'm not sure I have that source code anymore. I can check later. Using that function on the Cb and Cr planes and "inflating" both of them into a single CbCr plane was all I did, I believe. I passed the original Y' plane along unchanged.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and I don't understand how to use vImageConvert_PlanarToChunky8 as well. Specifically, I don't get what should I pass to destChannel parameter. Can you hint please ?